# Email Validator in Django Ninja

Tags: python, pydantic, django-ninja

I found that Django Ninja uses Pydantic.
I have created a Schema from Django model,

```
class UserSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Config:
        model = User
        model_fields = ["username", "first_name", "last_name", "email"]


class CreateUserSchema(UserSchema):
    password: str
```

and I used `CreateUserSchema` in my view, and import `EmailStr` from `Pydantic`

```
...
async def register(request, user_data: schemas.CreateUserSchema):
    email = EmailStr(user_data.pop("email"))
...
```

I want to validate `EmailField` but, it cannot validate, and store anything in the field.
How can if fix it?

Comment: Assume this `register` is an endpoint-method. What happens if you remove the `async`? Using the model-type for body-parameters should trigger automatic validation like explained in [Django Ninja: How-To Guides > Parsing Input > Request Body](https://django-ninja.rest-framework.com/guides/input/body/?h=validate#results).

Answer (score 2):

A simple way using `django-ninja` and `pydantic` (pydantic needs to be installed with the email flag: `pip install pydantic[email]`) is following:

```py
class UserSchema(ModelSchema):
    email: EmailStr

    class Config:
        model = User
        model_fields = ["username", "first_name", "last_name", "email"]


class CreateUserSchema(UserSchema):
    password: str
```

So it will validate the email directly in schema validation

Answer (score 0):

I see a similar issue in django-ninja: [ModelSchema automatical validation #443](https://github.com/vitalik/django-ninja/issues/443). It is currently open and has a similar topic; namely apply model field validation automatically for ModelSchema(s).

So, until a more general solution is found I suggest calling your Django model's [`clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) or even [`full_clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) method inside your request handler:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from ninja.errors import ValidationError as NinjaValidationError
...

class UserSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Config:
        model = User
        model_fields = ["username", "first_name", "last_name", "email"]
...

# and in your incoming request handler
@router.post('/example')
def register(request, payload: UserSchema):
    user = models.User(**payload.dict())
    try:
        user.clean()
    except ValidationError as err:
        raise NinjaValidationError(err.messages)
    ...
```